# Socket.IO https/ssl in iOS and Python App Engine

Tags: python, ios, ssl, google-app-engine, socket.io

I've built an GCP App Engine service in Python 3.7 using Flask and an iOS app in Swift.. the apps are using Socket.IO to connect and transfer data.

Everything works great with a local deployment, however when deploying to GCP the SocketIO connection is never upgraded to a socket and is left defaulting to long polling.

This seems to be an issue with ssl / https, though hours of googling have brought me absolutely no joy. There just isn't sufficient documentation on what i'm supposed to add to get https working over the socket.

The code in my opinion is fairly unremarkable, but here it is anyway

App Engine

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = socket_secret
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

@socketio.event()
def connect():
    print("******* connection established *******")


@socketio.on("update")
def update(json):
    handle_update(json)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting")
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

iOS

```
    private lazy var socketManager: SocketManager = {
        let config: SocketIOClientConfiguration = [.log(true),
                                                   .compress,
                                                   //.connectParams(["ssl_verify": false]),
                                                   //.forceWebsockets(true)
        ]
        let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: domain)!, config: config)
        return manager
    }()
```

I'm assuming I need to know two things...

1. How to create an SSL cert on my App Engine and give it to my Python `Socket.io` instance
2. How the `SocketManager` on iOS uses the cert in the same way cert pinning works over `NSURLConnection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is Standard env, it could be due to the fact that Standard env doesn't support websockets. See [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments), [Google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/cDR1Ru2ak88)

See [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35886348)

Comment: Well god damn, this is a massive pain... thanks, let me try flexible

Comment: Can't get a flexible environment to deploy atm, so still waiting on confirmation of this... I haven't forgotten though